# Get values of static fields with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

The following class gets with reflection the field names of class Test:

```
public class MainClass {

    public class Test {
        public static final int field1 = 1;
        public static final int field2 = 2;
        public static final int field3 = 3;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Field[] fields = Test.class.getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field: fields) {
            System.out.println(field.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

This prints:

```
field1 
field2 
field3 
this$0
```

But I also need to print the initialization values (filtering `this$0`), for example:

```
field1 - 1 
field2 - 2 
field3 - 3
```

There's a `getInt(Object o)` method in `Field`, but since there's no instance (the fields are static) I cannot use it. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use `null` as argument representing instance if method/filed is static.

Comment: That worked perfectly